# Where can I find a list of 'os' and 'dist' options for Travis-CI / Multi OS Build Matrix

Tags: github, travis-ci

[Per the Travis-CI documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/) you can run tests on different operating systems and distributions amongst them.

A the time of writing, a Google search doesn't turn up a list of **all** the possible os and dist options. All one has to go from is the [following example](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/#Example-Multi-OS-Build-Matrix) which provides the following under the ***build matrix*** sub heading:

> There are many options available and using the `matrix.include` key is
>   essential to include any specific entries. For example, this matrix
>   would route builds to the Trusty beta build environment and to an OS X
>   image using Xcode 7.2:
>
> `matrix:
>     include:
>       - os: linux
>         dist: trusty
>         sudo: required
>       - os: osx
>         osx_image: xcode7.2`

Yet there's no guidance on what options are available for the `os`, `dist`, or `osx_image` keys. Does anyone know where to find these values?

Comment: I'm guessing that info is buried somewhere in https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks, but I think the saner option would be to bug the travis people to update the docs.

Comment: That's a good suggestion - I thought I might have overlooked something obvious. I think the generally accepted way to test on different platforms ends up being to use [docker](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [The Build Environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments), the "Virtualization environments" section contains a table listing the different operating systems Travis CI currently supports. Currently (2016-08-15) that includes:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition 64 bit (without `sudo`)
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition 64 bit (with `sudo`)
- OS X Mavericks
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server Edition 64 bit (with `sudo`)

As it also states, the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server image is the default, so you can only switch to one other Linux distribution, namely `trusty`. Given that the `dist` property only have one possible value, I guess the need to "list all possible values" is limited.

However, for OS X, the above is not the end of the story. [The documentation about the OS X environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment) lets us know that the `osx_image` property can have a range of different values that will change both the version of Xcode as well as the version of OS X:

- **OS X 10.11**

  - `osx_image: xcode8` (Xcode 8 beta 4)
  - `osx_image: xcode7.3` (Xcode 7.3.1)
  - `osx_image: xcode7.2` (Xcode 7.2.1)
- **OS X 10.10**

  - `osx_image: xcode7.1` (Xcode 7.1.1 GM)
  - `osx_image: xcode7` (Xcode 7)
  - `osx_image: xcode6.4` (Xcode 6.4)
  - `osx_image: beta-xcode6.3` (Xcode 6.3)
- **OS X 10.9**

  - `osx_image: beta-xcode6.2` (Xcode 6.2)
  - `osx_image: beta-xcode6.1` (**Default**, Xcode 6.1)

What's interesting about this is that `beta-xcode6.1` is listed as the default image for OS X, which has an ancient version of Xcode and OS X and additionally seems to be in beta (whatever that means). It might thus be a good idea to explicitly configure one or more `osx_image` versions in the `matrix` if you're going to build for OS X.

**Update**: As of October 2017, the default is OS X 10.11 with Xcode 7.3.1, and the latest available is OS X 10.12 with Xcode 9.